# AngularJS material mobile layout not responsive

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to make a responsive website and the issue that I am having is the mobile version just looks like a super tiny version of the desktop.

```
<body ng-controller="body" >

<div layout="column">
    <div flex>
        I'm above on mobile, and to the left on larger devices.
    </div>
    <div flex>
        I'm below on mobile, and to the right on larger devices.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The example above on a desktop has the two `flex` divs next to each other in a row, if i re-size the browser the divs eventually go from inline to one under the other just like it supposed to. The problem is that on a mobile the divs stay inline and the font looks tiny and it basically just looks like a full very tiny website. It doesn't seem like the responsive part is kicking in. I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need viewport meta in head tag.
Please reference:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag